# Getting multiple ranges of dynamic strings inside a string

Tags: ios, range, substring

I have been trying to get multiple ranges of a string inside a string.
To change the color of those strings.

For changing the text Color i have used **UILabel+FormattedText.h** Category.

For e.g in string :- @"@hello @test testing #label"

I want those substrings to be shown in red color which are staring with @ or #.

Now in the output @hello @test #label will be in red color and testing will be in normal color.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through something like this. At the end "rangesArray" will contain the ranges of strings with "@" and "#" as prefix and "attrString" will be the attributed string that convert those strings to red colored text.

```
    NSString * test = @"@hello @test testing #label";

    NSArray *array = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableArray *rangesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSInteger prevStringLength = 0;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:test];

    for (NSString *str in array) {
        if ([str hasPrefix:@"@"] || [str hasPrefix:@"#"]) {
            [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(prevStringLength, str.length)];
            [rangesArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(prevStringLength, str.length)]];
        }

        prevStringLength += (str.length + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks poorva. I did it using NSScanner. You can see below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it done using below method

```
+(void) setTextColor:(NSString *)stringToScan Label:(UILabel *)label CharacterToCheck:(NSString *)characterToCheck Color:(UIColor *)color
{
    NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringToScan];
    [scanner scanUpToString:characterToCheck intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before CharacterToCheck
    while(![scanner isAtEnd]) 
    {
        NSString *substring = nil;
        [scanner scanString:characterToCheck intoString:nil]; // Scan the # character
        if([scanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&substring])
        {
            // If the space immediately followed the CharacterToCheck, this will be skipped
            if([substring rangeOfString:characterToCheck].location == NSNotFound)
            {
                substring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",characterToCheck,substring];
            }

        [substrings addObject:substring];
        }
        [scanner scanUpToString:characterToCheck intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before next CharacterToCheck
    }



    for(int i=0;i<[substrings count];i++)
    {
        NSString *str = [substrings objectAtIndex:i];

        NSRange range = [stringToScan rangeOfString:str];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [label setTextColor:color range:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length)];
        }
    }
}
```